# Spring Security session timeout then throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, spring-security, web.xml

when my session timeout and i submit any post method then throws this exception.

- my spring security code ->

  ```
     <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" 
      invalid-session-url="/login.do?invalid=true"
      session-authentication-error-url="/login.do?authFailed=true"/>
  ```

Request method 'POST' not supported
    at

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:196) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at 

org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:284) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:231) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:298) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) [servlet-api-6.0.29.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api-6.0.29.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) [catalina-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857) [coyote-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) [coyote-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [coyote-6.0.29.jar:6.0.29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```